# regex for searchterm

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search

I need help in constructing RegEx for the search function on my website. I am currently using JQuery framework. The goal is to go through paragraphs in XML and returns node that contains keywords inserted in the search text field.

For example, user may enter "***Lorem Sed Pellentesque***" in the search text field and I would like to use the keywords enter in the text field and go through the paragraph and find these keywords no matter the position of the keywords. Below is the sample of the paragraph:

> Nullam accumsan leo ultrices nisi consectetur blandit. Integer
>   aliquam, urna nec vestibulum posuere, est ante sollicitudin tortor,
>   non feugiat eros orci vitae dui. In lacus nulla, feugiat vitae porta
>   vel, lobortis eget ligula. **Sed** egestas aliquet orci ut varius.
>   **Pellentesque** ullamcorper magna eu sem convallis elementum.

So in this case, this paragraph will be considered as one of the results since it contains "Sed" and "Pellentesque" keywords.

Is it possible to construct RegEx that can go through the whole paragraph? It does not matter if it is case-sensitive or not.

Any help is really appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regular expressions are not at all related to jQuery.

Comment: I know. I am just wondering if you can use jQuery with RegEx together.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript... so you can do anything what JavaScript can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (not very robust but will work for alphanumeric keywords):

```
var keywords = $('input').text().replace(" ", "|");
var re = new RegExp(keywords, "gi"); // make it global, case insensitive
var matches = re.exec("paraText");
```

Although, you can do it without regex:

```
var keywords = $('input').text().split();
$(keywords).each(function() {
  if(paraText.indexOf(this) > 0) {
    // keyword found
  }
});
```

If you want to match between word boundaries, you need some regex like this:

```
var keywords = $('input').text().split();
$(keywords).each(function() {
  var re = new RegExp("\\b" + this + "\\b");
  if(re.test(paraText)) {
    // keyword found
  }
});
```

Comment: You may also want to add \b for word boundaries around the input words.   This will keep the regex from matching where one of the keywords was part of a larger word.

Comment: Do you mind explaining more on RegExp("\\b" + this + "\\b") part? Shouldn't this be $(this) ?

Comment: `\b` is to search between word boundaries; so if your keyword is "Sed" and search text is "SedGre", there won't be a match (It'll match if the text is "Sed Gre"). Inside the string, you need to escape the slash. You don't need `$(this)` as these are just strings and not dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    var a=text.replace(/(Nullam|ligula|in)/ig,'<b>$1</b>');
    $('#ttt').html(a);
    </script>
<div id='ttt'>Nullam accumsan leo ultrices nisi consectetur blandit. Integer aliquam, urna nec vestibulum posuere, est ante sollicitudin tortor, non feugiat eros orci vitae dui. In lacus nulla, feugiat vitae porta vel, lobortis eget ligula. Sed egestas aliquet orci ut varius. Pellentesque ullamcorper magna eu sem convallis elementum.</div>
```

sample there: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/q8S7E/

Comment: just curious.

what is the difference between?
var a=text.replace(/(Nullam|ligula|in)/ig,'<b>$1</b>');

with 

var pattern = new RegExp ("Nullam|ligula|in", "ig");
var a=text.replace(pattern ,'<b>$1</b>');

It gives out different result. Do you mind share your thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: I really don't know :) I used perl style regexp, may be behaviour will different on different syntax